# Trigger if value from one table changes from Null to other value

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have 2 tables House and AlarmInstall...
I need to create a trigger that will update a boolean Atribute "isInstaled" to false in my House table when i insert a uninstallDate (diferent then Null) in my Alarm Install Table.
I am a bit of a noob when it comes to trigger in SQL server. Any help will be appreciated!!!

These are the 2 tables

```
            [dbo].[AlarmInstall](
                [AlarmInstallId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                [HouseId] [int] NOT NULL,
                [InstallDate] [date] NOT NULL,
                [uninstallDate] [date] NOT NULL,
                [Model] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,


            [dbo].[House](
                [HouseId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                [StreetId] [int] NOT NULL,
                [DoorNr] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
                [CityId] [int] NOT NULL,
                [IsInstalled] [bit] NULL,
```

Both tables are related thru HouseId that is PK in House Table and FK in AlarmInstall

tried with this trigger but all my Houses get flagged as true!!!
GO

```
            CREATE TRIGGER STATECHANGE
               ON  dbo.AlarmInstall
            AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
            AS 
            BEGIN
                -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
                -- interfering with SELECT statements.
                SET NOCOUNT ON;

            update dbo.House SET IsInstalled=1
            From  dbo.AlarmInstall a
            inner join inserted i on a.HouseId=i.HouseId
            and i.InstallDate is not null
            END
```

Comment: What is it you need help with? What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? What is the DDL of your tables? Can you provide sample data and expected results (preferably as DML statements to go with your DDL statements, if not then table formatted `text`)?

Comment: Both tables are related thru HouseId that is PK in House Table and FK in AlarmInstall

Comment: That doesn't address any of the questions I asked you here, Pedro.

Comment: Sorry @Larnu my comment wasn´t to your question... had forgotten to specify the relation between the 2 tables...

Comment: Just updated with the tables

Comment: Are you sure that [uninstallDate] is NOT NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could help: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4024/sql-server-trigger-after-update-for-a-specific-value/

You could also use a calculated field for isInstalled with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE House(
   HouseId int NOT NULL,
   [...]
   uninstallDate date NULL,
   isInstalled bit AS CASE WHEN uninstallDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

But I don't see the value of creating it like this (or using a trigger), because when you don't have this field, you can always calculate it in a query:

```
SELECT
   HouseId,
   [...]
   uninstallDate,
   CASE WHEN uninstallDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS isInstalled
FROM
   House
```

// Added to originat answer

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.StateChange
   ON dbo.AlarmInstall
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   BEGIN
      IF UPDATE(uninstallDate)
      BEGIN
         DECLARE @houseId int
         DECLARE @uninstallDate date
         SELECT @houseId = HouseId, @uninstallDate = uninstallDate FROM inserted

         UPDATE dbo.House
         SET IsInstalled = CASE WHEN @uninstallDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
         WHERE HouseId = @houseId

      END
   END
```

Comment: OK, you defined the tables after my post - in this case you have to join the tables, and this will only work when you have a 1:1 relation, as in other cases the uninstallDate could be something in one case and NULL in the other - then it will not work, or what should it be then?

Comment: Thanks @michael-tobisch for you feedback will give it a try! The example you sent is for updating value of OrderStatus in the same Table. i need to update isInstalled Atribute from Home Table when uninstallDate from table Alarminstall gets changed.

Comment: One home will have only one install and one install is only associated with one home. I will trigger true for isinstalled wenever the installdate is filled and a false for wenever a uninstalledDate is filled.

Comment: If you have a 1:1 relation, it is the same as you have it in one table, just join the two tables by the HouseId and create a unique index on AlarmInstall.HouseId.

Comment: manage to create the trigger... could you please check my trigger to see what is wrong with it??? all my houses get flagged as true...

Comment: You don't have a WHERE condition in your trigger, that's why all rows are set to 1. I added a create trigger in my answer.